# Automatically update master branch of fork on GitHub (for free)

Tags: github, automation, fork

This is my first post in Stack Overflow so bear with me (and sorry for my poor English skills).

I know how to use Github, how to fork, and how to **manually** update a fork when I want. So far, so good.

What I want now is to find a way (using some sort of on-line service like AppVeyor) that will automatically keep my fork in sync with the original repository that I forked from.

I want some automated process to:

- Pull the latest changes from the master branch in the upstream repository
- Push the latest changes to the master branch in the fork repository

Is there any way to do that - for free?

I know I could have a virtual machine on Amazon, Azure, etc... And automate that, but that would cost me money.

Is there any way to automate that via IFTT recipe or custom build in AppVeyor or something like that?

Comment: AppVeyor automation is possible here, I'm planning to learn this way too.

Comment: Any idea how to configure that in AppVeyor, Vasily? The problem I see is that I cannot trigger AppVeyor on the original project (because I am not the owner). I can only trigger the AppVeyor on my own fork (which doesn't make sense as I won't be touching it)

Comment: If you're not the owner, that might be a problem. In this case you need some regularly scheduled git polling procedure (like Jenkins does it for triggering builds instead of web hooks).

Comment: `git ls-remote` command can help to check that the upstream repo is up-to-date.

Comment: Build schedule can be set in AppVeyor (see "Build schedule" option in the "General" section of the project settings). You need a crontab expression for that.